# php echo select options

Tags: php, mariadb

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "DBNAMES";
?>
<div>
        <?php
            $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
            if ($conn->connect_error){
                die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            }
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM names";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                echo "Names: ";
                echo "<select name='siteoption'>";
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result )) {
                    echo '<option value = "'. $row['ID'] . '">' . $row['Name'] . '</option>';
                }
                echo "</select>";
            }
        ?>
</div>
```

**Question:** How do i give my drop down a default value that the user can't select?

**Exp:** `<option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>` i want to achieve this but in a php `echo`

Comment: *"that the user cant select?"* - Can't or can? If it's "can't", I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Personally I prefer to do one database check and put these into an array. From there on i use the array to build the dropdown. Then you can style what something has to do. For example if A = B then selected/hidden etc.

Comment: @Edwin That isn't what the OP is asking here.

Comment: @RonnieOosting How would i accomplish this?

Comment: Assign a variable to a POST array and use that in a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Sorry, was to fast with my comment. I've edited it.

Comment: @RonnieOosting My ping was meant for Edwin, sorry about that. I edited it.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner `Can't` Sorry for the spelling. Typed so fast didn't even see

Comment: @NewToPHP Do you know how to connect with the database and parse all data into an array?

Comment: That possible duplicate, doesn't fully answer this. Pretty sure about that; only partly.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner the OP asked: "How do i give my drop down a default value that the user can't select?" How is this not answered in the linked SO?

Comment: @Edwin did you read the 2nd part? *"**Exp:** "Please Choose" then all my data that comes from database"*

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner - As I read the OP's question, the question is how to add a "Please choose" at the top of the list that can't be selected.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson well I don't know where to throw myself with their *"**Exp:** "Please Choose" then all my data that comes from database"*. But hey, if people think it is a duplicate, then I'll hammer it.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner so? you change the name from `-- select an option --` to what the OP has and the rest you do with while in php (as he already does)

Comment: I've moved on here. No further pinging please.

Comment: `<option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>` this is all that i want to achieve but in a php echo

Comment: As this has been closed, Ive wrote a small example:  `<?php $dropdown = [
 0 => 'Please Choose',
 1 => 'Option One',
 2 => 'Option Two',
 3 => 'Option Three',
 4 => 'Option Four',
]; ?>

 <select>
  <?php foreach ($dropdown as $key => $value): ?>
   <option id="<?php echo $key; ?>" <?php echo ($key == 'Something') ? 'disabled' : ''; ?>> <?php echo $value; ?></option>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
 </select>`

Comment: @RonnieOosting Thanks will work with it

Comment: No problem, feel free to contact me at facebook messenger if you have questions.